# Purview over comment moderation on Stack Overflow blog

Tags: support, moderation, blog

Who moderates the comments on the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog)? Are they Stack Overflow moderators? Stack Exchange moderators? (In the sense that they are elected by the community, whichever community that may be.) Are they Stack Exchange Inc. employees? Trusted, high-reputation users, maybe? Or a combination of any of those?

I've searched Stack Overflow Meta as well as Meta Stack Exchange, using the term "blog moderation" (without the quotes), but, while perusing the first couple of results pages, couldn't identify anything of "relevance" or with a high number of "votes" that would answer my question.

So, which group of people is in charge of moderating comments submitted to the Stack Overflow blog?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments on [stackoverflow.blog](https://stackoverflow.blog) are moderated by employees of Stack Overflow. Specifically, our marketing and digital content teams.

Comment: Hi John, how do we alert staff to a rude/abusive comment or comment reply that got approved on a blog post?

Comment: Hey Tyler - you can alert the Community Team, who will evaluate and bring comments that need attention to the marketing team.