# How does comment moderation on the Stack Overflow blog work?

Tags: support, blog

I posted a comment on the currently featured Stack Overflow blog post [Tales from documentation: Write for your dumbest user](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/13/tales-from-documentation-write-for-your-dumbest-user/) over 7 hours back, and it said the comment was awaiting moderation.

I checked again (a few moments back) and the comment I replied to had a published reply, but my reply wasn't yet published. Happy to publish screenshots, but I'm just curious to know if my comment was not approved because I disagreed with the word choices in the blog post, or if it was completely automated.

Comment: It definitely goes through [Akismet](https://akismet.com/privacy/), not sure if SO do anything special with them after that

Comment: They're manually reviewed by employees, as far as I understand.

Comment: They are manually reviewed by the marketing department.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387562/682840